# jdk 1.8 duplicate null check in String.equalsIgnoreCase

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, conditional-statements

String.equalsIgnoreCase is implemented as follows (Oracle JavaSE 1.8 )

```
public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString) {
    return (this == anotherString) ? true
            : (anotherString != null)
            && (anotherString.value.length == value.length)
            && regionMatches(true, 0, anotherString, 0, value.length);
}
```

I wonder if the `(anotherString != null)` check is necessary, as in `this != anotherString` already indicates that `anotherString` is not null.

Comment: It is perfectly possible for `anotherString` to be null at the point where that condition is checked. Without that check,`equalsIgnoreCase(null)` would throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: this == anotherString indicates that anotherString can't be null, the != doesn't

Comment: "**duplicate** null check" - there is only one null check in that code (and this is needed). Should not be too hard to reproduce this method without the check and see what happens if `anoptherString` is null...

Comment: Why do you think `this != anotherString` implies `anotherString != null`? If it was just a mental slip, that's fine -- we all make them. :) But if upon thinking about it you still think the logic holds, I suggest you edit the question to include your reasoning, so that we can address that as well. It may be more fundamental than just this specific question.

Comment: yeah, it's a mental slip.. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you are right and see what's going to happen when we call `equalsIgnoreCase(null)`:

1. `this == anotherString` is false;
2. `anotherString.value.length == value.length` - We are getting a NPE on `anotherString.value`.

Therefore, `anotherString != null` is necessary and crucial here.

---

> `this != anotherString` already indicates that `anotherString` is not `null`.

No, it doesn't. It can only state whether `this` and `anotherString` not equal.

For instance, both `this != null` and `this != "test"` return `true`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think this is a stupid question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's necessary.

`this != anotherString` may imply `anotherString` is a different String or `anotherString` is `null`

Answer (score 1):

No. Without `anotherString != null`, suppose `this` is `foo`, `anotherString` is `null`:

```
this == anotherString ---> false,
anotherString.value.length == value.length ---> NullPointerException will be thrown
```